# how to simplify angles (in degrees) in R?

Tags: r, trigonometry, degrees

I am building a manual / by-hand / judgmental factor rotation function.

Obviously, rotating the two-dimensional coordinate system `270°` is the same as `-90°` and `720°` is the same as `0°`.

I'd like to simplify user input such that all values are between `-180°` and `180°`.

How can I do that elegantly in R?

Ps.: Or would it make more sense to store values from `0°` to `360°`? 
Users may want to rotate clock- and counterclockwise, so I think `-180` to `180` may be more intuitive from a UX point of view.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like?

```
x <- 90 + c(0,360,720)
x
# [1]  90 450 810

(x*pi/360) %% pi
# in radians:
#[1] 0.7853982 0.7853982 0.7853982

# in degrees
((x*pi/360) %% pi)*360/pi
#[1] 90 90 90
```

Comment: yes! Should've answered that myself, thanks so much.

I wrapped your answer in a function and transformed it to `-180°` to `180°` in the below answer.

Answer (score 5):

Do you just want to have all numbers being their remainder mod 360?

So, you can do all sorts of sums and always end up with an answer between 0 and 360.

```
to_degrees <- function(x) x %% 360 
to_degrees(720)
[1] 0
to_degrees(-90)
[1] 270
to_degrees(300 + 100)
[1] 40
```

EDIT:

If you want the numbers to be between -180 and 180, just take away 180 at the end.

`to_degrees <- function(x) x %% 360 -180`

Now

- 0 -> -180
- 360 -> 180.

Comment: yes, thanks – in addition, I wanted the values to be between `-180°` and `180°` (rather than `0°` and `360°`) for UX reasons. Or is that a stupid idea?
Added clumsy solution below.

Answer (score 1):

based on @Pascal's answer, here's a slightly expanded version that (clumsily?) transforms the angles to a range from `-180°` to `180°` (for UX reasons):

```
  simplify.angle <- function (angle.raw) {  # simplify angles to -180° to 180°
  angle.360 <- ((angle.raw*pi/360) %% pi)*360/pi
  if (angle.360 > 180) {
    angle.simple <- angle.360 - 360
  } else if (angle.360 < -180) {
    angle.simple <- angle.360 + 360
  } else {
    angle.simple <- angle.360
  }
  return(angle.simple)
```

}

This yields:

```
> sapply(c(-90, 270, 630, -450, -181), simplify.angle)
[1] -90 -90 -90 -90 179
```